# vim: library of common substitutions without plugins?

Tags: vim, vimrc, vim-plugins

I would be wanting to perform thinks like `:'<,'>s/^\ \ \ \ //` in an abbreviated form, like `:'<,'>s_lw` (no matter what would actually be that `s_lw`) using `vim` base functionality, initially trying not to rely in extensions like [CommandAlias : Make aliases to vim command](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4250).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use command-line mode *abbreviations* for that:

```
:cnoreab s_lw s/^\ \ \ \ //
```

The advantage of abbreviations over mappings (`:cnoremap`) is that you can still type this (e.g. inside a search) without it expanding unintentionally.

Comment: Note for readers: `@:` can be used for repeat the action.

Answer (score 2):

The example you give could probably be done with `<`.

Anyway, you can use a custom command:

```
" remove 4 leading spaces on the current line or a range
command! -range=% SLW execute <line1> . ',' . <line2> . 's/^ \{4}//'

" usage 1:
    foo
:SLW<CR>
foo

" usage 2:
    foo
    bar
vj
:'<,'>SLW<CR>
foo
bar

" usage 3:
    foo
    bar
:,+SLW<CR>
foo
bar
```

a visual mode mapping:

```
xnoremap ,slw :s/^ \{4}//<CR>
```

or a commandline mode mapping:

```
cnoremap slw s/^ \{4}//
```

or a commandline mode abbreviation like in Ingo's answer.